# Why GDB shows all zero values for a large map

Tags: go, memory, gdb

I am a newbie in GDB/Go. I try to use GDB to debug a performance problem, where increasing an (already-large, ~800K entries) map by a few items (~400 entries) suddenly speeds up processing. I guess this is related to memory. I tried to print out the map variable in GDB before and after adding those entries, as shown in the attached screenshots. In the slightly-bigger-map case, all the values printed by GDB are zero. Does anybody know what is causing this? I am guessing this is related to some memory optimizations performed by Go.

[image: GDB screenshot with a bigger map showing all zero values]

[image: GDB screenshot with a slightly-small map showing normal values]

Comment: Go initializes things to their zero values so you could just be seeing the 400 new empty entries in the map. Hard to say without code to demonstrate what you're seeing.

Comment: gdb is good for C and C++. A debugger with better support for Go is delve, which is a pleasure to use. See https://github.com/go-delve/delve

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow! Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for how to make it easier for people to help you